# Will deleting and reinstalling create-react-app bring problems to my existing project?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I've been working on a create-react-app app since October last year. I am now starting another one but I get the 
`A template was not provided. This is likely because you're using an outdated version of create-react-app. Please note that global installs of create-react-app are no longer supported.` 
error.

I read the documentation and to solve this, I should first uninstall create-react-app `npm install -g create-react-app` and then install it again.
I wondered if that will cause any problems to my other (very important) project and running it with `npm start`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created an app using `create-react-app` , it already installed react packages and scripts in your old project. You don't need `create-react-app` anymore to run this project.

Feel free to uninstall the package and just use `npx create-react-app` to create your new projects.